# DataGridView ComboBox Cell error when closing form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I have a ComboBox column on my datagridview, the ComboBox is bound to a datasource for the values.

On Form Load I add rows and data to my DataGridView from a database table, here's how I add the value to the combobox column. This code is inside a loop, hence the rowindex variable.

```
Dim combo As DataGridViewComboBoxCell
combo = CType(Me.DataGridView1(3, rowindex), DataGridViewComboBoxCell)
combo.Value = sqldr("company_code")
```

It works fine for me, the combobox value is changed to what I had in my table and I can change the value of the cell using the combobox but if I try closing the form I get this error which just keeps repeating if I press Ok, I have to stop debugging just to exit the application.

[image: Error]

Comment: please post your full .vb file

Comment: @SurajS I added a breakpoint to every event, nothing fires. I don't even have a formclosing event.

Comment: please show us the entire function, it is not possible to find errors with 3 lines of code.